# Help finding Delta T for a known position displacement with known accel/decel, etc

Tags: kinematics, velocity, displacement, optimization

I'm looking for an equation to find the time it will take for a position displacement to happen, given known $V_{max}$, a (known) constant acceleration, deceleration, jerk, and displacement... and an initial velocity of 0.

I am trying to estimate/calculate the time it will take for a servo motor axis to travel a certain distance.  Once I know the estimated time of that move, I can solve for jerk for the other axis.  That way, I choose an optimally "slow" speed for whichever axis has a shorter move distance to make the maximum use of my time.

FYI, this is a pick and place XY robot gantry.

Comment: Assuming $\Delta x =   (a/2)*t^2 + (j/6)*t^3$, finding t is the same thing that resolving a [cubic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function)

Comment: Thanks, I'll start with that and see what I come up with.

Comment: If you agree with the equation I give above, and if you have problems, I will try to give you a complete answer.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks.  So...  I am doing a move with parameters:

Comment: Oops.  Repost:    I am doing a move with parameters:  Vmax = 1000 mm/s, accel = 1000mm/s^2, decel = 1000mm/s^2, Jerk = 1000 mm/s^3, and the Displacement is 2000mm.  I have timed this move at around 4.0 seconds, so that should be the answer, but I need to get the equation that results in this for different input variables.  (note accel and decel are not necessarily the same).  Thanks for looking at it, I am a bit out of my league on the mathematics.

Comment: You will have to precise in detail the [profile](http://www.pmdcorp.com/news/articles/html/Mathematics_of_Motion_Control_Profiles.cfm) and its phases.I suppose your profile has 3 phases: 1st phase :constant acceleration $accel$, 2nd phase: constant (negative) $jerk$ = acceleration rate change, at the end of this phase, the acceleration is negative and has the (negative) value $deccel$. Then the 3rd phase would be a phase of constant decceleration $deccel$. Tell me if it is correct, or give me the details of all the phases of your profile.

Comment: I think that is pretty much it... the profile starts with constant Accel, but is jerk limited. It then uses a decel value which is also jerk limited on the decel side of the move.  It is a pretty standard point to point motion profile, nothing fancy.  I'm using an S Curve move, not a Trapezoidal move... I can calc the time of a Trapezoidal move with a lot less complexity.  Thanks.

Comment: $jerk$ is the rate of change of acceleration (or decceleration). so must I understand "jerk limited" as $jerk = 0$ during the accelerating and deccelerating phases (1st and 3rd phases). If acceleration is constant in the 1st phase, and decceleraton is constant in the 3rd phase, that means that $jerk = 0$.

Comment: I understood jerk as the acceptable rate of change in acceleration, as in a limit... so, 0 jerk would say that accel was allowed to change 0 units over time, which would make the move not happen.  A jerk limited move is one where the jerk value provided is acting to slow down the change in acceleration.  It smooths the corners out on a trapezoidal move.  The lower the jerk number, the more rounded the corners are.  If you provide a jerk number high enough that no smoothing occurs (they are really sharp), I consider that move to be "not jerk limited".  Am I wrong about how that works?

Comment: I think I was not reading correctly your precedent commentary, in fact your [profile](http://www.pmdcorp.com/news/articles/html/Mathematics_of_Motion_Control_Profiles.cfm) was a S curve (fig 1 a), with a maximum acceleration $accel$, a maximum decceleration $deccel$, a maximum speed. $Jerk$ indicates the increase of acceleration in phase 1 and the dicrease of decceleration in phase 7.  I need one more information, this is the duration of the phase 4, when there is the maximum speed. This is a parameter but I don't know it.

Comment: Time in Phase IV should be calculable, though I don't know how to calculate it...

Comment: You are right..., see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you the result of my calculus without the details:

The result is :

$$ \Delta t = \frac{\Delta x}{V_{Max}} + \frac{1}{2}(\frac{V_{Max}}{a} + \frac{a}{j}) + + \frac{1}{2}(\frac{V_{Max}}{d} + \frac{d}{j})$$

where :

$\Delta t$ is the total time.

$\Delta x$ is the total displacement.

$a$ is the maximum acceleration.

$d$ is the maximum decceleration.

$j$ is the jerk.

$V_{max}$ is the maximum speed.

As a test, with your values :

$\Delta x = 2 m, a = 1m/s^2, d = 1m/s^2, j = 1 m/s^3, V_{max} = 1m/s$, I find :

$$ \Delta t = \frac{2}{1} + \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1}) + + \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1}) = 2 + 1 + 1 = 4$$

which is the correct result.

So I am quite confident in the formula.

[EDIT]
The formula to obtain jerk is :

$$j = \frac{a + d}{2 (\Delta t - \large \frac{\Delta x}{\large V_{max}}) -  V_{max}(\large \frac{1}{a} + \large\frac{1}{d})}$$

[EDIT 2]

The used model is :

Phase 1  : constant (positive) jerk $j$

Phase 2  : constant acceleration $a$

Phase 3  : constant (negative) jerk ($- j$)

Phase 4  : constant speed $V_{Max}$

Phase 5  : constant (negative)  jerk  ($- j$)

Phase 6  : constant decceleration    ($d$)

Phase 7  : constant (positive)  jerk  ($j$)

---

In the formulas above, there are constraints, more precisely the duration of the phases 2, 4, 6  must be positive:

$$\Delta t_2 = \frac{V_{Max}}{a} - \frac{a}{j}\ge 0$$
$$\Delta t_4 = \frac{\Delta x}{V_{Max}} -\frac{1}{2}(\frac{V_{Max}}{a} + \frac{a}{j}) - \frac{1}{2}(\frac{V_{Max}}{d} + \frac{d}{j})  \ge 0$$
$$\Delta t_6 = \frac{V_{Max}}{d} - \frac{d}{j}\ge 0$$

If one of these constraints is not satisfyed, this means that the hypothesis taken for the model are incoherent, so we need another model.

Comment: THANKS!  I appreciate the time you spent to help me.  I'll move that to the PLC and see how it goes.  I still  need to figure out solving for j when delta T is known, but I can probably manage that.  Keep up the good work.

Comment: Here is the PLC calc for time as you mentioned above: `fMoveTime_s := (fDeltaPos_M / fVMax_M) + (0.5)*( (fVMax_M / fAccel_M) + (fAccel_M / fJerk_M) )+ (0.5)*( (fVMax_M / fDecel_M) + (fDecel_M / fJerk_M) );`

Comment: NO, your first formula for jerk is not correct. I made an edit in the answer for the correct formula. Your last formula (for time) seems correct. By the way, what is PLC?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I removed that comment.  The correct PLC code for finding Jerk should be:  `fJerkCalc := (fAccel_M + fDecel_M) / ( ( 2 * (fMoveTime_S - (fDeltaPos_M / fVMax_M))) - (fVMax_M * ((1/fAccel_M)+(1/fDecel_M)) ) );`

Comment: PLC is a 'programmable logic controller', basically a microcontroller or real time computer for industrial use.  I'm using it to coordinate and control a 4 axis pick and place robot.  I'm very close to having it right, but something is still off just a bit somewhere..  The formulas seem good though.

Comment: Your formula seems correct. Your robot stuff seems very interesting. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks.  Speaking with my boss, who is a motor guru, he said it probably is better to control velocity instead of jerk to get my desired result.  Jerk works in theory, but since the feed forward gains in the motor controller only work at constant velocity, I'll get a lot of position lag and such, which is probably why my move times are not as accurate as I hoped for.  So, I can just solve for vMax I guess, it will not dampen the accel/decel as much as I wanted, but he thinks that should be enough.  Thanks again.  I would send you a video, but I guess this site wont allow private messages..?

Comment: So, something is still wrong here.  If I fill in 50,000 for Vmax, I end up with a longer number (6 seconds or so) than moving at only 1000.

Comment: I made an [EDIT 2] in the answer. In fact, this model has constraints on the durations of the phases 2,4,6, which must be all positive. If these constraints are not satisfyed (and in you example, I think that the the problem is with the duration of the phase 4), this means that the model is no more valid (because hypothesis data are incoherent with this model).Practically, this means that maybe the total displacement is not big enough, or maybe acceleration or decceleration are not big enough (while conserving the ratio $a/j$ and $d/j$ not too big).